# Is there any sorting algorithm that can generate all the sets of notes?

Tags: sorting

As we can visualize and listen to a sorting algorithm sorting an array, does exist an algorithm that can generate any set of notes? More precisely, does exist a sorting algorithm so that exists a program given a set of notes to give us an array so we can hear that set of notes by sorting that generated array with the algorithm?

Comment: Your question is not precise enough, you might benefit from trying to formalize it a bit further. If you allow the algorithms to do "unproductive steps" in the meantime, then sure, it will suffice for the algorithm to inject unnecessary swaps that produce what you want. This paper https://www.mipmip.org/tidbits/pasa.pdf for example circumvents this caveat.